# Monero daemon is not connecting to peers during initial sync

Tags: monerod, synchronization, full-node

On a WIndows server 2016 machine, running monero 0.18.2.2-release.
New to monero.
Sorry if this is a basic thing but I've been troubleshooting this for 3 hours now.
When I start monerod.exe even with administrative privileges, and type "set_log 1",
all I see on the terminal is:

```
2023-05-18 21:46:26.931 I 0Connect failed to 51.79.173.165:18080
2023-05-18 21:46:31.944 I 0Connect failed to 66.85.74.134:18080
2023-05-18 21:46:36.957 I 0Connect failed to 88.198.163.90:18080
2023-05-18 21:46:41.971 I 0Connect failed to 88.99.173.38:18080
2023-05-18 21:46:47.000 I 0Connect failed to 176.9.0.187:18080
2023-05-18 21:46:52.060 I 0Connect failed to 192.99.8.110:18080
2023-05-18 21:46:52.060 W Failed to connect to any of seed peers, continuing without seeds
2023-05-18 21:46:58.077 I 0Connect failed to 88.198.163.90:18080
2023-05-18 21:47:03.089 I 0Connect failed to 88.99.173.38:18080
2023-05-18 21:47:08.125 I 0Connect failed to 176.9.0.187:18080
2023-05-18 21:47:13.138 I 0Connect failed to 192.99.8.110:18080
2023-05-18 21:47:18.151 I 0Connect failed to 37.187.74.171:18080
2023-05-18 21:47:23.155 I 0Connect failed to 51.79.173.165:18080
2023-05-18 21:47:28.192 I 0Connect failed to 66.85.74.134:18080
2023-05-18 21:47:33.205 I 0Connect failed to 88.198.163.90:18080
2023-05-18 21:47:33.205 W Failed to connect to any of seed peers, continuing without seeds
2023-05-18 21:47:33.205 I No available peer in white list filtered by 1
2023-05-18 21:47:33.205 I No available peer in gray list filtered by 1
2023-05-18 21:47:34.239 I Failed to connect to any, trying seeds
2023-05-18 21:47:34.254 I HTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /gethashes.bin
2023-05-18 21:47:34.254 I [127.0.0.1:55552 INC] calling /gethashes.bin
2023-05-18 21:47:34.254 I HTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /get_transaction_pool_hashes.bin
2023-05-18 21:47:34.254 I [127.0.0.1:55552 INC] calling /get_transaction_pool_hashes.bin
2023-05-18 21:47:34.254 I HTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /getblocks.bin
2023-05-18 21:47:34.254 I [127.0.0.1:55552 INC] calling /getblocks.bin
2023-05-18 21:47:34.276 I HTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /gethashes.bin
2023-05-18 21:47:34.276 I [127.0.0.1:55552 INC] calling /gethashes.bin
2023-05-18 21:47:39.251 I 0Connect failed to 37.187.74.171:18080
```

Over and over, and its been like this for around 1 hour.
I have tried also starting the daemon with monero-gui-wallet, with the same result.
Is the process usually like this?
I have set inbound and outbound firewalls rules allowing all TCP connections to ports 18080 and 18081, and still nothing. Should I also try messing with my router's firewall?
Thanks for your time.